# How to limit total number of digits in a decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex which validates if a string is a decimal number.
Also this checks if it has at most 9 decimals after ".".

```
^[-]?[0-9]+([\.][0-9]{0,9})?$
```

I need to add another check, which limits the total number of digits.

Mention: I need the total number of digits to be less then 38, including the decimal after the point, thus I cannot add the range just to decimals before the point.

valid ex:

```
      -12345678901234567890123456789.123456789

      123456789012345678901234567890.1

      -1.123456789
```

Comment: or simply `str.length <= n`? where `n` is max length of the value you want to validate.

Comment: `-123456789012345678901234567890.123456789` , is valid???????/ it contains `39` digit

Comment: i added by mistake another decimal
-12345678901234567890123456789.123456789 is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with positive look ahead assertion **[`/^-?(?=[.\d]{0,39}$)\d{0,38}(\.\d{1,9})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/vW4lR3/3)**

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).css('color', /^-?(?=[.\d]{0,39}$)\d{0,38}(\.\d{1,9})?$/.test(this.value) ? 'green' : 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vW4lR3/3)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: you have an awesome response here, but Wiktor Stribiżew was first. Thanks!

Comment: @aurelius : glad to help :)

Comment: This solution restricts the *whole string length* (except the first hyphen) regardless whether it is a digit or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){n}\D*$)[-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,9})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where `n` is the limit argument for the amount of digits in the input string.

*Example*:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){7}\D*$)-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,9})?$
```

will match `1234.567`, but will not match `1234.56` and `1234.5678`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK1xL3/1)

Now,

> I need the total number of digits to be less then 38

Just use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){38})-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,9})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This `(?!(?:\D*\d){38})` lookahead will fail the match if there are 38 (not obligatorily consecutive due to `\D*`) digits in the string.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){38})` - the [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#negated) that will try to match 0+ non-digits (`\D*`) followed with a digit *exactly 38 times* and if it matches that text, no match will be returned
- `-?` - an optional (1 or 0) hyphen (no need to place it into a character class as it is not a special regex metacharacter here)
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits (use `\d` instead to make it shorter)
- `(?:\.[0-9]{0,9})?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) sequence of:

  - `\.` -  a literal dot
  - `[0-9]{0,9}` - 0 to 9 digits (again, `\d{0,9}` is shorter)
- `$` - end of string

And **if you need to only check the *integer part* to have less than 38 digits**, use

```
^(?!(?:[^\d.]*\d){38})[-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,9})?$
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK1xL3/2)

Comment: Wow! Never imagined this was possible with regex alone. But `str.length <= n` will still be faster and more readable :)

Comment: @gurvinder372: Everything can be done without a regex. Sometimes, a regex is just more convenient. Readability depends on one's regex  knowledge level. For me, this is very readable. I will add an explanation.

Comment: @aurelius: I checked the demo strings in the question, and came to the conclusion you need the 3rd version of the regex that I added. Please confirm which one works best, and I will explain it in detail.

Comment: both of them work so thanks, i will use the second one :)

Comment: your second solution doesn't work perfectly ^(?!(?:\D*\d){39})-?[0-9]+([\.][0-9]{0,9})?$

negative ex: "123." this should not be validated. So, a digit is necessary after point

Comment: It is your regex, I did not tamper it too much. Surely, if you do not want to mathc `4.`, use `^(?!(?:\D*\d){39})-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,9})?$` (replace `{0,9}` with `{1,9}` to make a digit after `.` required). The most common pattern for a float/integer is `\d*\.?\d+`, to allow values like `.56`. So, perhaps, you could even use `/^(?!(?:\D*\d){39})-?\d*\.?\d{1,9}$/`.

Comment: BTW, 38 in the limiting quantifier will disallow 38 digits in the input string, and allow up to 37. You wrote *I need the total number of digits to be less then `38`* - no idea, but please check.

Comment: So, you wanted to limit the whole string to 39 characters except the firs hyphen? `/^-?(?=.{39}$)\d*\.?\d{1,9}$/`?